# Clear "Temporary Internet Files" from a server

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, winapi, browser-cache, winhttp

Basically I use http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201 for clearing the cache.

But in a article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383990(v=vs.85).aspx it is mentioned that the above KB cannot be used from the server.

They asked to use WinHTTP, can anyone suggest me a way to implement this.

I searched in net but can't get any proper article for this implementation.
I am a beginner too, so find it difficult for implementing.

Please help me anyone...
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry, i have edited, thanks

Comment: Why are you programmatically attempting to clear the cache?

Comment: In our main product, we use a command to clear the cache, at present we are using file.Delete() to clear the Temp files, but it is not efficient, so we are implementing based on KB. In our product we create dll for the customers

Comment: Do you want to clear the client's temporary files from the server? That shouldn't be possible. Or does your server generate temporary internet files somehow? In that case any application that can host an IE control can clear temporary internet files as well.